# Reading a file from Lambda

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I a created a sample serverless AWS Step Functions application with netcoreapp3.1. In one of the steps, I need to read from a json template which I am storing in the project directory. A folder I called json_templates

But on the server, I am getting the error below

```
{
 "error": "DirectoryNotFoundException",
"cause": {
"errorType": "DirectoryNotFoundException",
"errorMessage": "Could not find a part of the path 
'/var/task/json_templates/Initiation_template.json'.",
"stackTrace": [
  "at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)",
```

The way I am reading the file from the code is as shown below

```
     string fileName = "json_templates/Initiation_template.json";

        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Comment: How did you implement the lambda? Zip upload? If you are using zip run `chmod -R o+rX .` inside your lambda function folder before zipping and uploading.

Comment: I used the template that Visual Studio provides to create a Serverless project. To deploy, I am right clicking and selecting 'Publish to AWS Lambda'

Comment: I would double check that you have the Properties (right click on it in Solution) on that JSON file regarding "Copy to Output Directory" a)If Newer or b) Always

Answer (score 0):

While troubleshooting I noticed that the file is **not being included** in the zip that is stored on S3.

Will focus investigation on how the zip file gets created for serverless projects.